# Format date object such that its precision ends in seconds

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In javascript, is there a way to format the date object so the milliseconds are removed. The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to remove all duplicates in a mongo database that were created around the same time. Using the current date object this is not possible because no two object would ever be created at the exact same time since their milliseconds would differ. Basically, is there a way to format the date object such that if two date objects have the same value in seconds (not ms) they would be considered equal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in javascript you can do:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getMilliseconds()); // 0-999 value
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d.getMilliseconds()); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Date` object and specify the exact time (precision) you want. You can do it like this:

```
var startDate = new Date(2014, 5, 10, 2, 3, 4)
// in the shell it will be displayed like ISODate("2014-06-10T02:03:04Z")

var endDate = new Date(2014, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5)
// in the shell it will be displayed like ISODate("2014-06-10T02:03:04Z")

db.collection.remove({ created : { $gt : startDate, $lt: endDate }});
```

This will remove all documents from the collection that are created between July 10 2014, 2h 3min 4sec and July 10 2014, 2h 3min 5sec.